# Commenting app for all other apps in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I have an app for forum. It has three classes **Tag**, **Question** and **Answer**.

models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.tag_name)

class Question(models.Model):
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    asked_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.short_description)

class Answer(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    for_question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.description)
```

I also want to have comments for **Question**, **Answers** and also for **other parts** of my apps. What is the best way to achieve this? I mean, what is the right way to design the django models for this use case? Do I have to use *content types* for this?

Comment: Django has its builtin comments model, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/ Can it meet your demand?

Comment: I thought, it was deprecated. But I checked the url and didn't much like this `comment framework has been deprecated and is no longer supported. Most users will be better served with a custom solution`. Can you please show me the other way?

Comment: How did you get on with the below answer, Robin?

Comment: @halfer I ended up using the generic foreign keys.

Comment: Would you add an answer to that effect please, and then acknowledge Craig's effort in some fashion? Ignoring their kind effort is not polite.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about adding a ForeignKey class Comment in your models.py?

The model is pretty straightforward:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
     *attached_to* = models.ForeignKey(CONTENT)
     body = models.TextField()
     parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name="children")

other fields...
```

Will you be using the same comments for each type of content or do you want unique behavior for each type of content?

For one app, the above model is the simplest.

For multiple apps, you're better off - I think - breaking out Comments into an independent app which call on the appropriate apps in the ForeignKey ([Foreign key from one app into another in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323763/foreign-key-from-one-app-into-another-in-django))

If you're looking for a universal comment system, the above model will work, but you'll likely want to check out GenericForeignKey ([Django Model field with multiple types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256744/django-model-field-with-multiple-types)).